# preprocessor to replace javascript keywords

Tags: javascript

I am using the [Angular version of the $q library](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) however this would also be relevant for the [original q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Usage example:

```
$q
  .when(someFunction)
  .then(function(){
    // ..
  })
  .catch(function(){
    // ..
  })
  .finally(function(){
    // ..
  });
```

Unfortunately some function names (e.g. `finally`) conflict with javascript keywords.
From the Angular reference:

*"Because finally is a reserved word in JavaScript and **reserved keywords are not supported** as property names by ES3, you'll need to invoke the method like `promise['finally'](callback)` **to make your code IE8 and Android 2.x compatible**."*

ECMA-262, the official standard, available at [http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), states:

> **7.6.1.1 Keywords**
>
> The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may *not* be used as
>   Identifiers in ECMAScript programs.
>
> ```
> break           do              instanceof      typeof  
> case            else            new             var 
> catch           finally         return          void 
> continue        for             switch          while 
> debugger        function        this            with 
> default         if              throw            
> delete          in              try
> ```

This means that the first example has to be changed into the following code to get it working with IE8:

```
$q
  .when(someFunction)
  .then(function(){
    // ..
  })
  ['catch'](function(){
    // ..
  })
  ['finally'](function(){
    // ..
  });
```

As this code is harder to maintain I am looking for a javascript preprocessor (maybe a grunt task) which turns the first example into the IE8 compatible version.

Is there such a preprocessor?

Comment: There isn't one that I know of. You'd probably have to implement your own.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight do you know a good reference project with source map support?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. When I implemented a [C-style preprocessor](http://csserver.evansville.edu/~wg24/senior_project/other/node.js/preprocessor.js), I didn't use a source map.

Comment: It's pretty easy to do this actually with esprima and escodegen.

Comment: On a sidenote, in original q library one can use `fin` instead of `finally` and `fail` instead of `catch`.

Comment: @lorefnon in `$q` those aliases don't exist though, you can use a decorator over `$q` to add them though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your friendly neighborhood Stef Panner created such a tool just for that a few months ago. It's called [es3-safe-recast](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es3-safe-recast). There is also a [grunt task](https://github.com/phpro/grunt-es3-safe-recast) for it.

Let's go through what it does. First it requires the Esprima package for JS syntax tree analysis and recast on top of it that is built for these conversions:

```
'use strict';
var esprima = require('esprima');
var recast = require('recast');
var Visitor = recast.Visitor;
var types = recast.types;
var namedTypes = types.namedTypes;
var builders = types.builders;
```

Then it contains a big map of all the identifiers - just like your list:

```
identifierToLiteral.finally = true; // here is `finally` for example
```

Here is how it parses the tree and replaces it with a visitor:

```
var ES6Safe = Visitor.extend({
  visitProperty: function(node) { // go through all properties
    // check if need to replace name with literal
    if (namedTypes.Identifier.check(node.key) && identifierToLiteral[node.key.name]) {
      node.key = builders.literal(node.key.name);
    }

    return this.genericVisit(node);
  },

  visitMemberExpression: function(node) { // and all member expressions
    var property = node.property;
    var newNode;
    // check if need to replace name with literal
    if (namedTypes.Identifier.check(property) && identifierToLiteral[property.name]) {
      newNode = builders.memberExpression(node.object, builders.literal(property.name), true);
    } else {
      newNode = node;
    }
    return this.genericVisit(newNode);
  }
});
```

Finally, it runs the code through recast:

```
ast = recast.parse(source, { esprima: esprima } );
new ES6Safe().visit(ast);
code = recast.print(ast).code;
```

Producing the safe version of the above code.